# How will Washington State Long Term Care tax affect workforce joining in the future

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, washington

Washington state is planning to bring in a new Long Term Care tax that is going to be 0.58% of the total income. To opt out, tax payers need to buy a private policy before 2021/11/01 and then apply to opt out between 2021/10/01 - 2022/12/31.

How will this affect people who will start working in WA after 2022/12/31? Say, someone moving from state of Florida to WA, or someone who will start working in 2025.